# C# having trouble with thread safety I suppose?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Hello guys I have a couple of questions as to why these things are happening. Firstly I have the initial firing off of however many processes you set numOfAsynchEx equal to. This should start two different threads with two different instances of ExecuteThread class and have two of the SAME method (ThreadProcess) but with different variables correct?

```
int numOfAsynchEx = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfAsynchEx; i++)
        {
            if (entryQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                ExecuteThread eT = new ExecuteThread(entryQueue.Dequeue()
                    new startNextThread(startNextThread));

                Thread newThread = new Thread(eT.ThreadProcess);
                newThread.Start();
                metrics.TotalAttempted++;
                metrics.ThreadsRunning++;
            }
        }
```

This is the callback method in the same class:

```
private void startNextThread(ParsingInfo info)
    {
        metrics.ThreadsRunning--;
        if (entryQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            metrics.TotalAttempted++;
            ExecuteThread eT = new ExecuteThread(entryQueue.Dequeue()
                new startNextThread(startNextThread));

            Thread newThread = new Thread(eT.ThreadProcess);
            newThread.Start();
            metrics.ThreadsRunning++;
        } 
        else if(metrics.ThreadsRunning == 0)
        {
            ThreadsDone = true;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** Here is the execute thread class
    public class ExecuteThread
    {

```
    private CatalogEntry entry;
    private startNextThread callBackDelegate;
    private ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
    private ParsingInfo parseInfo;

    public ExecuteThread(CatalogEntry entry, startNextThread callBack)
    {
        parseInfo = new ParsingInfo();
        this.entry = entry;
        callBackDelegate = callBack;

        createStartInfo();
        InstantiateProcess();
    }



    private void createStartInfo()
    {
        startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath);
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = + filePath + " " ;
    }

    private void InstantiateProcess()
    {
        fileParserExe = new Process();
        fileParserExe.StartInfo = startInfo;
        fileParserExe.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    private void Parse()
    {
        try
        {
            this.fileParserExe.Start();
            this.fileParserExe.WaitForExit();
            parseInfo.additionalMessage += fileParserExe.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            parseInfo.additionalMessage += e.ToString();
            parseInfo.additionalMessage += "Could not locate single file parser executable: " + exePath;
        }

    }

    public void ThreadProcess()
    {
        this.parseInfo.fileName = entry.fileName;
        this.parseInfo.startTime = DateTime.Now;
        Parse();
        this.parseInfo.endTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.parseInfo.SetElapsedTime();

        if (this.callBackDelegate != null)
        {
            this.callBackDelegate(this.parseInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, this is not firing off two threads at the same time and executing them asynchronously. It is doing one at a time. I don't understand why. Can anybody enlighten me?

**EDIT:** After playing around with it for awhile, when I commented out redirectStandardOutput and useShellExecute, the program worked PERFECTLY like it used to. My problem now is how do I redirect the output because I obviously can't do it that way?

Comment: Your code won't actually compile as it is - please give us a short but *complete* example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: how are you observing that they are not async?

Comment: You are mutating shared variables with apparently no synchronization. That is fraught with peril.

Comment: Try to place a break point inside the async method, if they run async, the break point should hit twice.

Comment: I tried to give as much as I can, but I cannot provide a fully working example for specific purposes. But this should be all you need to figure out the threading problem

Comment: And I appreciate the explanation on what I did wrong, but what do I do to fix it.

Comment: There is a chance that I am being very thick here and missing something...

Why don't you just use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

Comment: Because people told me not to try and limit the amount of threads the threadpool starts because you can get major problems. Maybe I was misinformed

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of suggestions...

- What is you entryQueue? Ordinary Queue{T} is not thread safe.
- You have a potential race condition since entryQueue.Count and
  entryQueue.Dequeue() are not done together atomically.
- You probably want to use Interlocked.Increment and decrement instead
  of plain ++ and --.

Comment: It is an ordinary queue. I will use a thread safe queue I suppose but will that fix all my problems? I don't see how the queue is the problem because it is supposed to just fire off 2 threads, then each threads callback method starts another thread.

Comment: @Joey I'm not sure whether this will solve "all your problems" but to have any chance of actually having a production-quality code, you must first address issues like these. I learned through my own mistakes that multi-threading is tricky and should be approached with utmost care and respect...

Comment: The entryQueue is a Queue<CatalogEntry>. How do I make this synchronized? CatalogEntries are something that is defined somewhere else.